# Why is my new internal hard disk is not showing up after reinstalling Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mount, drive-letter

I have a desktop with an Intel motherboard running Windows 7. A few days ago I bought a 2<sup>nd</sup> internal hard disk (SATA Seagate 500GB). I installed it and it was running normally. I copied some of my very important data on that new hard disk from my old internal hard disk whose data was deleted from the old hard disk.

Now for some OS problem, I had to reinstall Windows 7 on that old hard disk as it was before. The new hard disk is no longer showing in My Computer. How can I recover the data from the new HDD?

Comment: Have you checked the disk management console or the BIOS to see if the HD is visable?

Comment: Click Start, Right-Click over My Computer, select "Manage", select "Local Disks" - do you see your 500GB drive listed?

Comment: In the disk management it is showing.But not in My computer.

Comment: in manage there is no such option "local disk"

Comment: You need to assign the drive a letter.

Comment: @Breakthrough Yes it works thank u thank u very much...Those data was as important as my life....thank u.......

Comment: @Suvankar Mondal, not a problem, glad I could help.  I posted this as an answer (and expanded on the process a bit), so you can accept it if you would like.

Answer (score 6):

You need to assign (mount) the drive, by assigning it a drive letter.  Go to the Computer Management console (Start -> Run -> `compmgmt.msc`), and under Storage, go to Disk Management.  Right click on the drive/partition you want to mount, and click `Change Drive Letter and Paths`.

Click the `Add` button to add a new mount point, and then you can either mount it as a folder or a new drive (you can specify which drive letter it should use).